# how to handle Angular booting process exceeds the custom initialization time

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12, angular14

I am working in Angular 14. My issue is that if the application exceeds a custom time limit, for example, 3000 seconds, I have to show a message to the user. If it does not exceed the time limit, the application will render. To address this, I ran the code below in my application, but it's not working as expected, even in csr and this fix should work in server-side rendering (SSR). I don't know where I've made the mistake, but when I inspect it, the issue becomes clear.

```
Service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'; 

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppInitializationService {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  InitializationApplication() {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve();
      }, 6000); 
    }).catch(() => {

    });
  }
}
```

Module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { AppInitializationService } from './app-intialization.service';
import { APP_AFTER_INIT_TOKEN } from '../../tokenService';

export function initializeApp(appInitService: AppInitializationService) {
  return () => appInitService.InitializationApplication();
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    AppInitializationService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeApp,
      deps: [AppInitializationService],
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: APP_AFTER_INIT_TOKEN,
      useValue: () => {
        // This code will run after initialization
        console.log('Initialization complete.');
      },
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class AppInitializationModule {}
```

Please correct me or provide some answer with help